# How to toggle accordion menu using a check box and only that checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html, css, accordion

okay, so I got to disable other checkbox when one is active and managed to keep the transition animation for the panel of my accordion, however i can't figure out how to toggle the panel once i click on the "YES" checkbox.
what it does is when you click the "YES" checkbox, you still need to click the first accordion panel to open it. what I was looking for is when I click on the the "YES" checkbox, it should toggle the panel.

so far here's what I got

```js
<script>
   
 var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion_1");
 var i;

 for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
   acc[i].onclick = function() {
  this.classList.toggle("active");
  var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
  if (panel.style.maxHeight){
    panel.style.maxHeight = null;
  } else {
    panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
  } 
   }
 }
 
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#check_main').change(function() {
   $('#panel_main').toggle();

   var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion_main");
   var i;
 
   for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function() {
     this.classList.toggle("active");
     var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
     if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
     } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
     } 
    }
   }
  });
 });
 $(".checkbx, .GrpChk").change(function() {
  this.checked ? $("." + this.className).not(this).prop("disabled", true):$("." + this.className).not(this).prop("disabled", false);
 });
</script>
```

```css
button.accordion_1{
background-color: #eee;
color: #444;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 18px;
width: 100%;
border: none;
text-align: left;
outline: none;
font-size: 15px;
transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion_1.active, button.accordion:hover {
background-color: #ddd;
}

div.panel {
padding: 0 18px;
background-color: white;
max-height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

button.accordion_main{
background-color: #eee;
color: #444;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 18px;
width: 100%;
border: none;
text-align: left;
outline: none;
font-size: 15px;
transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion_main.active, button.accordion:hover {
background-color: #ddd;
}

div.panel_main{
padding: 0 18px;
background-color: white;
max-height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="box item1">
  <button class="accordion_main" id="check_holder"> TOTALLY RANDOM TEXT FOR TESTING
   <div class="check_box"> 
    <span>
     <form name="aForm" action="">
      <p>
      <label>
       <!--<input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check" value="1"> YES-->
       <input class="checkbx" id="check_main" name="Role" type="checkbox" value="yes"/>YES
      </label>
      <label>
       <input class="checkbx" name="Role" type="checkbox" value="no"/> NO
      </label>
      </p>
     </form>
    </span>
   </div>
  </button> 
  <div  class="panel_main" id="panel_main" style="display:none;">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
  <button class="accordion_1">Section 2</button>
  <div class="panel">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
  <button class="accordion_1">Section 3</button>
  <div class="panel">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
```

again, thanks guys in advance, I've been working on this for two days now, any help is well appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Give the class related to the button for section 2 and section 3 a different name.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
button.accordion, button.accordionn {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active,
button.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

div.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box item1">
    <button class="accordion" style="align:right;"> TOTALLY RANDOM TEXT FOR TESTING
            <ul style="display:in-line;">
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="check1" />
                    <label for="check1">YES</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="check2" />
                    <label for="check2">NO</label>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>

    <button class="accordionn">Section 2</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>

    <button class="accordionn">Section 3</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but the first panel still opens on click, i want it to open only if you click the "yes" check box. I'm not quite sure on how to do that. if its by using javascript i totally have no idea where to start.

thanks for replying by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I got it guys!
for reference here's what I was trying to do.

```
<div class="box item1">
            <button class="accordion_main" id="check_holder"> TOTALLY RANDOM TEXT FOR TESTING
                <div class="check_box"> 
                    <span>
                        <form name="aForm" action="">
                            <p>
                            <label>
                                <!--<input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check" value="1"> YES-->
                                <input class="checkbx" id="check_main" name="Role" type="checkbox" value="yes"/>YES
                            </label>
                            <label>
                                <input class="checkbx" name="Role" type="checkbox" value="no"/> NO
                            </label>
                            </p>
                        </form>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </button> 
            <div  class="panel_main" id="panel_main" style="display:none;text-align:center;">
                <div class="wrapper_acc">
                    <div class="box_acc a_acc">A</div>
                    <div class="box_acc b_acc">B</div>
                    <div class="box_acc c_acc">C</div>
                    <div class="box_acc d_acc">D</div>
                    <div class="box_acc e_acc">E</div>
                    <div class="box_acc f_acc">F</div>
                </div>
            </div>

<script>
        var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion_1");
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
          acc[i].onclick = function() {
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
            if (panel.style.maxHeight){
              panel.style.maxHeight = null;
            } else {
              panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
            } 
          }
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#check_main').change(function() {
                $('#panel_main').toggle("fast","linear");

            });
        });
        $(".checkbx, .GrpChk").change(function() {
            this.checked ? $("." + this.className).not(this).prop("disabled", true):$("." + this.className).not(this).prop("disabled", false);
        });
    </script>
```

instead of using the same transition effects for the other 2 panels i used this instead

```
$('#panel_main').toggle("fast","linear");
```

if you noticed i removed my css for div.panel.
tat was my major mistake, my the css was a conflict for the js. thanks guys!